# Does an existing varbinary(max) use FILESTREAM or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I check whether a `varbinary(max)` column is using FILESTREAM ?  For argument's sake, lets say that I inherited a DB and I wanted to check which `varbinary(max)` columns are using FILESTREAM and which are not.  I have tried running [`sp_columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx) which does not seem to show anything relevant.  If I "right-click -> properties" on the column from SQL Server Management Studio, it does not show anything either.  Does anybody know how to check for this?

Comment: Did you try to script the table creation to a new query window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(C.object_id) AS SchemaName
  , OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id) AS TableName
  , C.name AS ColumnName
FROM 
    sys.columns AS C
WHERE 
    C.is_filestream = 1;
```